# Is there any way to prevent FormBuilder elements to scroll to top of page?

Tags: flutter, flutter-form-builder

I have a long form with lots of textfield, datepicker, etc. When I click FormBuilder's checkbox, touchspin and radiobutton.Page scrolls to top until my clicked element is the first element. It's so annoying beacuse when I click touchspin's plus button at the middle of the page, it suddenly moves to top and I have to go on clicking at somewhere else.

Textfields, datepicker and dropdowns don't have this problem.

Is there any way to prevent this behaviour?

[Visual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gK27n.gif)

Comment: Did you find a solution? cuz i'm facing the same issue...

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue.
just update form builder package to latest version 7.1.1, it solved for me.
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_form_builder

see the change log for version 7.1.1 for mor update
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_form_builder/changelog